# Null terminated character array vs string object

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++, and I am looking very deeply into char arrays and string objects. I read that char arrays are null terminated with the character `'\0'` and the string object is not null terminated, unless you used the string library's member function, `c_str()`. Here I have some code, and I was expecting my first loop to run forever, but instead they both iterate approximately 6 times. Excuse my poor variables names, but can someone please explain to my why the string object does not cause an infinite loop.

I was thinking that any memory location that is being index into and has not been assigned a value is already represented by the char `'\0'`. If this is so, please let me know.

```
std::string is_terminated = "string";
char is_t[] = "string";

int i = 0;
while (is_terminated[i] != '\0') {
    std::printf("Element at index %d is %c\n", i, is_terminated[i]);
    i++;
}
std::printf("Times ran: %d\n", i);

int j = 0;
while (is_t[j] != '\0') {
    std::printf("Element at index %d is %c\n", j, is_t[j]);
    j++;
}
std::printf("Times ran: %d\n", j);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although `std::string` does not necesarily store `'\0'` (it's implementation-defined), [`operator[](size_type pos)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) returns the null character if `pos == size()`.

Comment: How can you be sure that `std::string` does not actually store `'\0'` at the end? Isn't it implementation-defined?

Comment: @Mikhail You’re right; I was referring to the public interface.

Comment: @Mikhail: *conceptually* it isn't stored, since all "sequence container operations" (e.g. iterating over the string through `begin()`/`end()`, adding a character through `push_back` and the like) behave "as if" the `\0` wasn't there.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, of course, _conceptually_, but I wrote _actually_ :) I'm not really sure, what _actually_ hapens, I don't know, whether this null char is preserved at the end of the string, or not. At least I'd expect `std::string` to always have enough capacity to quickly add it there on call of `c_str()`.

Comment: I think since C++11 `std::string` *has* to store the `\0`, because of copy-on-write (COW) being disallowed and the requirements of `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm not entirely sure, `c_str()` just requires constant time, which wouldn't forbid delaying the initialization to zero of the "one past last" element until it is called (provided that previously the internal buffer had been allocated with enough space). In practice I suppose that every implementation always stored the final `\0` immediately (and the standard could spell this out clearly instead of leaving it to interpretation, always having the `\0` at the end is a useful assumption to rely on in many cases, especially when dealing with C APIs).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Good point. But at the very least, space for the null terminator has to be present in the data buffer where the string elements are stored.

Comment: And whenever you look at the position of the terminator (`c_str()`, `data()`, or `operator[]`) it **is** there. So, how do we know if it isn't there when nobody is looking?

Comment: @BoPersson: `*(&s[0] + s.size())`

Comment: @MatteoItalia That is still guaranteed to yield (a reference to an object with the value) `char_type()`. `operator[]` is specified for the closed range [0, `size()`]. Even `data()` is specified in terms of `operator[]`.

Comment: @dyp: nope; `operator[]` yields a reference to `char_type()` if called passing `size()`, but here I called it with zero and moved to the "one after last" element through pointer arithmetic (which is completely outside the control of `operator[]`).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Ah, so `s.data()` is different from `&s[0]`? Interesting. Though I think one can deduce from the *Requires* in the spec of `data` that there must be a null terminator if `size() > 0`, which should also apply to `operator[]`.

Comment: @dyp: wait wait my fault; I parsed wrong the description of `data()`. I thought it said "A pointer `p such that *(p + i) == operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0, size()]`", but it actually says `p + i == &operator[]()`, so I guess that this settles the question?

Comment: @MatteoItalia d'oh, I've misinterpreted the *Requires* clause. I think your original suggestion was right: Both `operator[](size())` and `data()` may modify the last character to become a null terminator. The *program* in the requires clause probably refers to the user of the StdLib, not the implementer.